# how to move the cursor to previous lines which begins with > in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

When I copy and paste below code into bash, every line begins with **>** symbol; like:

```
cat  >hello.c <<"EOF"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
EOF
```

in bash:

```
cat  >hello.c <<"EOF"
> #include <stdio.h>
> 
> int main()
> {
>   printf("Hello World\n");
>   return 0;
> }
> EOF
```

I want to move cursor previous lines to edit those lines

Is it possible?

EDIT: I already tried bash shortcuts which none of them worked. It's different in lines with > operator*(I don't know its jargon in bash terminology, I hope somebody tells me)

EDIT2: I found the jargon of **>** , it's called [file redirection operator](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#File_Redirection)

So, I reiterate my question; how can I move the cursor beyond the file redirection operator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell with better editing capabilities](http://askubuntu.com/questions/706482/shell-with-better-editing-capabilities)

Comment: The second answer works for editing the prompt under that circumnstances, also Zsh allows to skim through the lines directly by using the up and down arrows.

Comment: @kos I know bash shortcuts, in my case with **>** it doesn't work.

Comment: I want to jump upper line

Comment: How come? Works for me in Bash `4.3.42(1)-release`. My suggestion was to use the method explained in the second answer (CTRL+X+E) to edit the full buffer into `EDITOR`. Or do you want to just go up one line? If the second one let me know so I can remove my close vote. However if there's a way to do that (I'm not aware of it) it's probably listed somewhere in the [GNU Readline documentation](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html).

Comment: @kos Negative. I already tried line editing shortcuts before I post my question. I even tried ascii codes of them. Your (CTRL+X+E) suggestion opens text in text editor and I can edit the upper lines but when I quit it with `:q` it adds one more `file redirection sign` which messes up the result.

Comment: The problem however is that you should type `EOF` and hit ENTER directly in the prompt, otherwise the final `EOF` it's interpreted as part of the file. Editing the buffer with CTRL+X+E, removing the `EOF` (or for that matter pasting the snippet without the last line), exiting `vim`, typing `EOF` and hitting ENTER works. I thought this should have been pointed out, but If you're still unhappy with this method I'll remove my close vote.

Comment: @kos Thank you for your efforts. I tried your suggestion again and again, unfortunately it even fails to save editing in Vim.  I tried adding EOF before and after. I ll work on it tommorrow.

Comment: Ok, feel free to drop me a comment for the removal, however I noticed that before you mentioned `:q`; you should use `:wq` to "save and exit". Saving is necessary to update the buffer with the modifications, otherwise the buffer will be left as before you started editing it. Also if you're more comfortable with another editor (say `nano`) you could add `export EDITOR=nano` at the end of your `~/.bashrc`, restart the shell / run `. ~/.bashrc` to apply the changes and from then the next buffers will be edited in `nano` instead of `vim`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34543/discussion-between-kenn-and-kos).

Answer (score 1):

### Should be easy

If you press the <kbd>up arrow</kbd> on your keyboard you should see the entire multi-line command. By pressing the <kbd>back arrow</kbd> you should be able to traverse the command even into previous lines.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The only difference is that when you use the **bash history** the `>` will not appear. In my case `TorrienAMD-->` is missing as in the example above.

### Modify Bash Prompt

Bash uses the variables `PS1` and `PS2` to set the prompt.

Perform`echo $PS1 && echo $PS2` to know the values of these variables for your terminal.

My output:

> `\[\e[0;32m\]\u\[\e[1;33m\]@\[\e[0;36m\]\h\[\e[0;33m\]\w\$\[\e[0;0m\]`
>
> `\h-->`

To understand the meaning of this read the list bellow obtained from [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html).

- \a : an ASCII bell character (07)
- \d : the date in "Weekday Month
  Date" format (e.g., "Tue May 26")
- \D{format} : the format is passed
  to strftime(3) and the result is inserted into the prompt string; an
  empty format results in a locale-specific time representation. The
  braces are required
- \e : an ASCII escape character (033)
- \h : the
  hostname up to the first '.'
- \H : the hostname
- \j : the number of
  jobs currently managed by the shell
- \l : the basename of the shell’s
  terminal device name
- \n : newline
- \r : carriage return
- \s : the name
  of the shell, the basename of $0 (the portion following the final
  slash)
- \t : the current time in 24-hour HH:MM:SS format
- \T : the
  current time in 12-hour HH:MM:SS format
- \@ : the current time in
  12-hour am/pm format
- \A : the current time in 24-hour HH:MM format
- \u
  : the username of the current user
- \v : the version of bash (e.g.,
  2.00)
- \V : the release of bash, version + patch level (e.g., 2.00.0)
- \w : the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a
  tilde
- \W : the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME
  abbreviated with a tilde
- \! : the history number of this command
- # :
  the command number of this command
- \$ : if the effective UID is 0, a
  #, otherwise a $
- \nnn : the character corresponding to the octal number nnn
- \\ : a backslash
- \[ : begin a sequence of non-printing
  characters, which could be used to embed a terminal control sequence
  into the prompt
- \] : end a sequence of non-printing characters

### One time change

Enter command `PS2=''` to change the value for current terminal only. This change will not be permanent.

### Set Custom PS1 & PS2 Values

When you open a terminal the file `~/.bashrc` is read for configuration here you can append at the end of file:

> `export PS2=''`

This will set a custom value for your PS2 variable and you should stop seeing the `>` character in every extra line of a command. Use command `reload` or close and reopen terminal to see changes.

### Better Customization

I however have a more complex configuration. Add the following code to `~/.bashrc`:

> `#file for personal modifications to the command line prompt (PSX)
>   if [ -f ~/.bash_PS ]; then
>      . ~/.bash_PS
>   fi`

This code means that if a file called `.bash_PS` is found at your home directory `~/` it will be read for execution.

Now create a file called `.bash_PS` at your home directory `~/`. Inside add the code:

> `export PS2=''`

Use command `reload` or close and reopen terminal to see changes.

In this approach you can use the file `.bash_PS` to set custom version of PS1, PS2, PS3 or PS4 as you want. I have a custom PS1 and PS2 with color codes included.

[image]

With either approach you should have set PS2 as an empty string **for your user** and the `>` should not appear anymore **for your user**. Empty or delete `.bash_PS` to return to default values. Remove the added line to `.bash_rc` if you used the old

### For all users

Add line `PS2=''` to file `/etc/bash.bashrc` under line starting with `PS1='some configured string'.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough info you posted. I tried your solution, it lets me edit when I hit enter after the final `Heredoc delimiter` **EOF**.   I only wondered if I moved cursor up to previous lines in bash. It seems to be impossible for the time being.